# Как передать выбранные в селекте значения в input?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ss.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  
  <div class="container lol text-center text-white" style="background-color: lightblue">
      <div>
      <h2>value1</h2><br>
        <select name="c1" class="custom-select col-md-3" id="bbb">
            <option selected>выбор</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
        
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="bat">Выбрать</button>
</div>

<div>
      <br><br>
      <h2>value2</h2><br>
        <select name="c2" class="custom-select col-md-3" id="bbb">
            <option selected>выбор</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
        
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="bat">Выбрать</button>
</div>
<br><br><br><br>
<input id="taggy" type="text" name="search">

</div>

</body>
```

нужно чтобы при выборе значения и нажатии на кнопку, оно записывалось в нижнее инпут поле, как пример, если в первом селекте выбрать значение "2", а во втором значение "5", то в нижнем поле должна быть цифра 25, заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const

g = i => i.value = `${typeof i.dataset.b !== 'undefined' ? i.dataset.b : ''}${typeof i.dataset.c !== 'undefined' ? i.dataset.c : ''}`,

f = g => ev => {
  document.forms.a.d.dataset [ev.target.name] = ev.target.options [ev.target.selectedIndex].value
  g (document.forms.a.d)
}

[document.forms.a.b, document.forms.a.c].forEach (s => s.addEventListener ('change', f (g)))
```

```html
<form name="a">
  <select name="b">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <select name="c">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <input name="d"/>
</form>
```